# WPF: Enabling a dropdown based on the value on another dropdown

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two comboboxes on my view.

What I want is that when I choose value 1 on ComboBox1, the ComboBox2 becomes enabled. However, when I choose any other value than 1 in ComboBox1, ComboBox2 stays disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb1" Margin="10,0" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="Please select" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbi11" Content="Option1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="cbi11_Selected" />
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbi12" Content="Option2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="cbi12_Selected"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbi13" Content="Option3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="cbi13_Selected"/>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="cb2" Margin="10,0" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="Please select" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbi21" Content="Option1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="cbi21_Selected" />
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbi22" Content="Option2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="cbi22_Selected"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbi23" Content="Option3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="198" Selected="cbi23_Selected"/>
</ComboBox>
```

And your Code behind:

```
private void cbi11_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        cb2.IsEnabled = true;
    }
private void cbi12_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        cb2.IsEnabled = false;
    }
private void cbi13_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        cb2.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: @Timo Kiander is that what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this properly then you are asking the wrong question as your view model will do most of the work for you

assuming you have a ViewModel like this (using [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx))

```
public class VM:BindableBase
{
    public ICollectionView Combo1Options {get,set}
    public ICollectionView Combo2Options {get,set}

    private object _Combo1Value;
    private object _Combo2Value;

    public object Combo1Value 
    {
        get { return _Combo1Value; }
        set 
        {
            if(SetProperty(ref _Combo1Value, value))
            {
                Combo2Options .Refresh();
                PropertyChanged(nameof(Combo2Enabled));                    
            }
        }
    }

    public object Combo2Value 
    {
        get { return _Combo2Value; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Combo2Value, value); }
    }
    public bool Combo2Enabled => Combo1Value != null;//or what ever logic defines if combo2 is required

}
```

then you would just bind to your view model

```
<ComboBox ItemSource={Binding Combo1Options }, SelectedItem={Binding Combo1Value }/>
<ComboBox ItemSource={Binding Combo2Options }, SelectedItem={Binding Combo2Value } IsEnabled={Binding Combo2Enabled}/>
```

By using CollectionView's you gain the ability to filter the combobox items so i would recommend it